# Anchor Tag in Oracle PL/SQL Script

Tags: html, oracle

I have got a requirement in hand. I have an existing PL/SQL package which will send a mail to a user whenever a contract is created. There is a seperate procedure inside the package which will have the mail body. As part of the new enhancement, I want to include a URL link, say,

"Please CLICK HERE for assistance"

And when the user clicks on "CLICK HERE" in the mail body, they should be redirected to a web page , say, "www.google.com".

Is this solution feasible in PL/SQL script?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks, 
Priya

Comment: @user122641 - Is the script sending a plain text email?  Or an HTML email?

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

```
declare
  smtp_host   VARCHAR2(256) := '<your smtp host';
  smtp_port   PLS_INTEGER := < your port >;
  smtp_domain VARCHAR2(256) := '<your domain>';
  conn        utl_smtp.connection;
begin

  conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(smtp_host, smtp_port);
  utl_smtp.helo(conn, smtp_domain);

  utl_smtp.mail(conn, 'aaa@bbb.com');
  utl_smtp.rcpt(conn, 'aaa2@bbb.com');

  utl_smtp.open_data(conn);

  utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn,
                          utl_raw.cast_to_raw('From' || ': ' ||
                                              'aaa@bbb.com' || utl_tcp.CRLF));
  utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn,
                          utl_raw.cast_to_raw('To' || ': ' ||
                                              'aaa2@bbb.com' ||
                                              utl_tcp.CRLF));
  utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn,
                          utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Subject' || ': ' || 'Hello' ||
                                              utl_tcp.CRLF));
  utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn,
                          utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Content-Type' || ': ' ||
                                              'text/html' || utl_tcp.CRLF));

  utl_smtp.write_data(conn, utl_tcp.CRLF);

  utl_smtp.write_data(conn,
                      '<p><h1>Hello</h1><a href="www.google.com">click here</a></p>');

  utl_smtp.close_data(conn);
  utl_smtp.quit(conn);

end;
```